# How to process macros in LEX?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

How do I implement `#define` in yacc/bison?

For Example:

```
#define f(x) x*x
```

If anywhere f(x) appears in any function then it is replaced by the right side of the
macro substituting for the argument ‘x’.

For example, f(3) would be replaced with 3*3. The macro can call another macro too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not usually possible to do macro expansion inside a parser, at least not C-style macros, because C-style macro expansion doesn't respect syntax. For example

```
 #define IF   if(
 #define THEN )
```

is legal (although very bad style IMHO). But for that to be handled inside the grammar, it would be necessary to allow a macro identifier to appear anywhere in the input, not just where an identifier might be expected. The necessary modifications to the grammar are going to make it much less readable and are very likely to introduce parser action conflicts. [Note 1]

Alternatively, you could do the macro expansion in the lexical analyzer. The lexical analyzer is not a parser, but parsing a C-style macro invocation doesn't require much sophistication, and if macro parameters were not allowed, it would be even simpler. This is how Flex handles macro replacement in its regular expressions. (`{identifier}`, for example. [Note 2] Since Flex macros are just raw character sequences, not token lists as with C-style macros, they can be handled by pushing the replacement text back into the input stream. (F)lex provides the [`unput`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-unput_0028_0029_002c-pushing-back-characters) special action for this purpose. `unput` pushes one character back into the input stream, so if you want to push an entire macro replacement, you have to `unput` it one character at a time, back to front so that the last character `unput` is the first one to be read afterwards.

That's workable but ugly. And it's not really scalable to even the small feature list provided by the C preprocessor. And it violates the fundamental principle of software design, which is that each component does just one thing (so that it can do it well).

So that leaves the most common approach, which is to add a separate macro processor component, so that instead of dividing the parse into lexical scan/syntax analysis, the parse becomes lexical scan/macro expansion/syntax analysis. [Note 3]

A C-style macro processor which works between the lexical analyser and the syntactic analyser could itself be written in Bison. As I mentioned above, the parsing requirements are generally minimal, but there is still parsing to be done and Bison is presumably already part of the project. Although I don't know of any macro processor (other than proof-of-concept programs I've written myself) which do this, I think it's a very flexible solution. In particular, the Bison syntactic analysis phase could be implemented with a push-parser, which avoids the need to produce the entire macro-expanded token stream in order to make it available to a traditional pull-parser.

---

That's not the only way to design macros, though. Indeed, it has a lot of shortcomings, because the macro expansions are not *hygienic*, respecting neither syntax nor scope. Probably anyone who has used C macros has at one time or other been bitten by these problems; the simplest manifestation is defining a macro like:

```
 #define NEXT(a) a + 1
```

and then writing

```
int x = NEXT(a) * 3;
```

which is not going to produce the expected result (unless what is expected is a violation of the syntactic form of the last statement). Also, any macro expansion which needs to use a local variable will sooner or later produce an incorrect expansion because of unexpected name collision. Hygienic macro expansion seeks to solve these issues by viewing macro expansion as an operation on syntax trees, not token streams, making the parsing paradigm lexical scan/syntax analysis/macro expansion (of the parse tree). For that operation, the appropriate tool might well be some kind of tree parser.

---

#### Notes

1. Also, you'd want to remove the token from the parse tree Yacc/bison does have a poorly-documented feature, YYBACKUP, which might possibly help be able to accomplish this. I don't know if that's one of its intended use cases; indeed, it is not clear to me what its intended use cases are.
2. The (f)lex documentation calls these *definitions*, but they really are macros, and they suffer from all the usual problems macros bring with them, such as mysterious interactions with surrounding syntax.
3. Another possibility is macro expansion/lexical scan/syntax analysis, which could be implemented using a macro processor like M4. But that completely divorces the macros from the rest of the language.

Answer (score 0):

yacc and lex generate c source at the end. So you can use macros inside the parser and lexer actions.

The actual `#define` preprocessor directives can go in the first section of the lexer and parser file

```
%{
// Somewhere here
#define f(x) x*x
%}
```

These sections will be copied verbatim to the generated c source.

Comment: I think they may be asking how to implement macro replacement in the parser being built, not how to use macros in the source files fed to Lex, Yacc, or Bison.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmm... Rereading the question, that might be... But this is a bit much to answer without any existing code